# HP desktop computer when powered on a light flashes on the motherboard and when it does (once every second) a cracking sound comes on the speakers

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, linux-mint, desktop

I had just got back from holiday, I booted the computer on and it was fine the next day I went on to do some work and nothing happened no CPU fans no nothing only a strange crackling sound I opened up the case and a light with the letters VIN next to it.
My computer model: HP Compaq dc7800
I have not changed or modified any of its parts, the only thing i have changed is it is running Linux mint  Cinnamon 64-bit if thats any help
thankyou any help is appreciated

Comment: You are certain light is purposely emitted and not a short arking?

Comment: @marshal craft i am pretty certian that it is purposely emitted as it does it on regular intervals

Comment: Cause other than fan and microphone and disk drives computer have no moving part to generate sound.

Comment: @marshal craft what about the speaker?

Comment: What do you think, best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is tagged "power supply" and you may have a lead there. Consider that power supplies are a common failure point for desktop computers. If you have the ability to swap your power supply for another known working power supply, you will be able to determine quickly if that is the problem.

Your power supply may have a component which is functioning enough to illuminate the LED, but then it fails, causing the light to extinguish.

Also consider to swap your power supply into a different working computer.

Power supplies are relatively inexpensive and often available at local shops for a slightly higher price than online sales.